# How to control every character of text in a p5.js Javascript sketch?

Tags: javascript, text, character, p5.js

**Overall Goal:** in a p5.js sketch consisting only of text (and a LOT of it!), I want to make each character an instance of a "Letter" class that will include things like font, style, size, position on canvas, and a bunch of methods.

The whole problem stems from how the p5 ["text"](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/text) function works. I can include the entire paragraph in a single text function where x = 50 and y = 50, and yeah, great, there is the paragraph - but I have no way at that point of accessing and modifying the *individual characters* within the paragraph. I can only access/modify the paragraph *as a whole.*

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[Link to see sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/brandtryan/sketches/RAQYODfkb)

I've tried using arrays, objects, maps, Map, SVG, html, CSS, etc. in order to give each character a unique id, assuming that must certainly be a prerequisite for what I'm doing. I finally achieved this by creating a new Map, and I can access each character by its index value.

I've tried creating a new p5 "text" function for each individual character, and I expected it to work, and it does.

What I haven't tried is figuring out a way to somehow iterate over each unique character and auto-magically turn each one into an instance of a Class. I expect this would help getting around having to create some 50,000 individual text functions, which is how many characters the entire sketch would have (including spaces). This is what I have so far:

```
let myString = "I'm a letter control freak!";
let letters;

function setup() {
  let charMap = new Map();

  for (let i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    charMap.set([i], myString[i])
  }

  letters = Object.fromEntries(charMap);

  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  textSize(22);
  fill(255);
  text(letters[0], 50, 50);
  text(letters[1], 57, 50);
  text(letters[2], 62, 50);
  text(letters[3], 82, 50);
  text(letters[4], 88, 50);
  text(letters[5], 102, 50);
  text(letters[6], 109, 50);
  text(letters[7], 115, 50);
  text(letters[8], 128, 50);
  text(letters[9], 135, 50);
  text(letters[10], 142, 50);
  text(letters[11], 155, 50);
  text(letters[12], 162, 50);
  text(letters[13], 170, 50);
  text(letters[14], 182, 50);
  text(letters[15], 195, 50);
  text(letters[16], 208, 50);
  text(letters[17], 215, 50);
  text(letters[18], 223, 50);
  text(letters[19], 236, 50);
  text(letters[20], 243, 50);
  text(letters[21], 250 + random(-3, 3), 50 + random(-3, 3));
  text(letters[22], 257 + random(-3, 3), 50 + random(-3, 3));
  text(letters[23], 264 + random(-3, 3), 50 + random(-3, 3));
  text(letters[24], 276 + random(-3, 3), 50 + random(-3, 3));
  text(letters[25], 288 + random(-3, 3), 50 + random(-3, 3));
  text(letters[26], 300 + random(-3, 3), 50 + random(-3, 3));
}
```